# Adding Avatar Image to Profile Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want build an Profile Picture Avatar Upload and display it in the Profile for every user.

Buts dont work with my method.

My Avatar Upload code:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile"><img src="/img/photos.png" height="80" width="80"> Upload Avatar:</label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="profileimage"></font></br>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Code where everyone see it in Profile:

```
      <div class="pull-left margin-left-25">
@if($user->profileimage == false) 
<img src="/img/icon.png"  height="80" width="80">
@endif
@if($user->profileimage == true) 
<img src="{{$user->profileimage}}" height="80" width="80">
@endif
```

ProfileController image content (Dont work for me):

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

         $file = $request->file('profileimage');

         $size = $request->file('profileimage')->getSize();
         if ($size > 500000) {
           session()->flash('errormessage','Image is too large');
           return redirect()->back()->withInput();
         }
         if (substr($file->getMimeType(), 0, 5) !== 'profileimage') {
           session()->flash('errormessage','File is not an image');
           return redirect()->back()->withInput();
         }

        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $path = $request->profileimage->store('uploads','public');
        } else {

          session()->flash('errormessage','Image is not valid');
          return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }

      }



     if ($request->image !== null) {
            $product->image = $path;
          }
```

What i have done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: show the error? did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form?

Comment: Check https://www.5balloons.info/upload-profile-picture-avatar-laravel-5-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) class?It will be so much easier than what you have coded. As the following,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:500000',
]);
```

Add the above code inside the method in which you store the file and do your things.

It will do the validation for you, then continue whatever you want to do with the file. For more options please check the link provided.

Also, in your HTML code. You need to have a form in first place, action and its method, so your code should be:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          <form action="{{ route('profile'}}" method="post">
          <label for="exampleInputFile"><img src="/img/photos.png" height="80" width="80"> Upload Avatar:</label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="profileimage"></font></br>
          </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

And in your *web.php*, you should have the following line:

```
Route::get('/URL', 'ProfileController@MethodName')->name('profile');
```

Comment: Must i add this just to my Controller or what you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes. In your _ProfileController.php_.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Are you sure that your HTML is saved as _name_.blade.php?